# Is it possible to get the name of a select list from an item that has just been removed from that list

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, selectize.js

I am attempting to update the values in an array after an item has been removed from a selectize list. To do this I need the `attr('name')` for the list. On the event of an `item_remove` the `$item` can get the select list, but it cannot find the `attr('name')` that I need.

The solution below is how I am doing this for an `item_add` event. You'll see that the `var thisSelect` gets the select list and from that, I can populate the values array with the actual list values.

```
/**
 * Add callback behaviour once a select element has been selected.
 */
    $('[data-type="select"]').each(function(i, v) {
        v.selectize.on('item_add', function (value, $item) {
            var thisSelect = $item.parents('.controls').find('select'),
                name = thisSelect.attr('name'),
                values = [],
                exclusiveSelected = thisSelect.find('option[data-exclusive="true"]:selected');

            if (exclusiveSelected.length) {
                values.push({
                    "value": exclusiveSelected.val(),
                    "label": exclusiveSelected.text().trim(),
                    "label-key": exclusiveSelected.attr("label-key")
                });

                thisSelect.val(exclusiveSelected.val()).trigger('change');

            } else {
                thisSelect.siblings('.selectize-control').find('.item').each(function(i, v) {
                    values.push({
                        "value": $(v).data('value'),
                        "label": $(v).text().trim(),
                        "label-key": $(v).attr("label-key")
                    });
                });
            }

            setMultipleFieldValues(name, values);
            validate(documentId, name, fields);
        });
    });
```

Below is my current solution for an `item_remove` event. A `Cannot set property 'values' of undefined` error occurs in the console because the values array cannot be populated due to the name of the list returning as undefined.

```
/**
 * Add callback behaviour once a select element has been unselected.
 */
    $('[data-type="select"]').each(function(i, v) {
        v.selectize.on('item_remove', function (value, $item) {
            var thisSelect = $item.parents('.controls').find('select'),
                name = thisSelect.attr('name'),
                values = [];

            thisSelect.siblings('.selectize-control').find('.item').each(function(i, v) {
                values.push({
                    "value": $(v).data('value'),
                    "label": $(v).text().trim(),
                    "label-key": $(v).attr("label-key")
                });
            });

            setMultipleFieldValues(name, values);
            validate(documentId, name, fields);
        });
    });
```

Attached is the select element I am trying to get the name "additionalWork" from

[image: html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses, the solution I managed to come up with involved getting the $input instead of the $item. For this, I could get the values in the list.

```
/**
 * Add callback behaviour once a select element has been unselected.
 */
    $('[data-type="select"]').each(function(i, v) {
        v.selectize.on('item_remove', function (value, $item) {
            var thisSelect = this.$input,
                name = thisSelect.attr('name'),
                values = [],
                exclusiveSelected = thisSelect.find('option[data-exclusive="true"]:selected');

            if (exclusiveSelected.length) {
                values.push({
                    "value": exclusiveSelected.val(),
                    "label": exclusiveSelected.text().trim(),
                    "label-key": exclusiveSelected.attr("label-key")
                });

                thisSelect.val(exclusiveSelected.val()).trigger('change');

            } else {
                thisSelect.siblings('.selectize-control').find('.item').each(function(i, v) {
                    values.push({
                        "value": $(v).data('value'),
                        "label": $(v).text().trim(),
                        "label-key": $(v).attr("label-key")
                    });
                });
            }

            setMultipleFieldValues(name, values);
            validate(documentId, name, fields);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the object as it's deleted. I'd suggest parsing a function into the `onDelete` callback

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/uZmcD/91/

```
$(function() {
  $('#select-name').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    onDelete: function(values) {
      item_remove_function($(this));
    }
  });
});

function item_remove_function($this) {

  var name = $this[0].$wrapper.siblings('select').attr('name');
  alert('select name = ' + name);

}
```